# Smart pointer implementation

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I won't write all the code, but I am looking at a smart pointer example implementation and it has:

```
template<typename T>
class smart_ptr
{

public:
    operator void*() const {return mPtr;}

    const T& operator*() const;
    T& operator*();

    const T* operator->() const;
    T* operator->();

private:
    T* mPtr;
};
```

1. What is the purpose of the first public function in the API?
2. Why do we need to const-overload the other two API methods?
3. Not only const-overload, but why have return-const-object variants?

Comment: The `operator*` and `operator->` functions don't appear to be overloaded, so it's not clear what you mean about const-overloading them.  They're `const` because they don't modify the smart pointer object.

Comment: 1. That's an [implicit conversion operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16615725/1139697). It enables you to use a `smart_ptr` whenever you would usually use a `void *`. Handle with care.

Comment: May be this article provides some enlightment for you: [Smart Pointers in C++](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31529).

Comment: @Wyzard do you mean they aren't overloaded because the return type differs? If they had all returned a const object, then they would have been const-overloaded?

Comment: It's not that the return type differs, it's that the *name* differs.  Overloading is when you have multiple functions with the same name but different signature.  The `operator*` and `operator->` functions have different names, so they're not overloads of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `operator void*` function is a type casting function, so you can write:

```
smart_ptr foo;
void* ptr = foo;  // The compiler will call `operator void*` here
```

or even

```
if( foo) {  // `operator void*` called to test boolean expression
  //...
}
```

The functions

```
const T& operator*() const;

const T* operator->() const;
```

are `const`, so you can call them on a const `smart_ptr`. Because they return `pointer/reference` to `const` object, this object can't be changed.

Comment: Regarding Q2/3 why couldnt the non-const methods also return a const object? A method's const-ness is unrelated to whether the return object is const or not?

Comment: yes these are two different things. Function const can be called on const object, this is why these are const functtions

Comment: What is the purpose of returning the const objects? I see the reasoning for providing const methods (operating on const smart pointers).

Comment: Why return a void*?
 Wouldn't   `operator T*() const {return mPtr;}` make more sense as it allows for code `T* rawPointer = smartPointer; // smartPointer is of type smart_ptr<T>`, while the void* variant does not?

Comment: Correct, operator T*() const {return mPtr;} would be preferred for this case. This is not the only thing that can be improved in this class though.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion operator looks to be intended to do two things:

1. Convert the smart pointer to `void*`. Generally pointers convert to `void*` but I'm not sure whether it is a good idea to do for smart pointers.
2. It will be used when testing objects to see what value they have when evaluated in a boolean context. That can be used to determine if the pointer is a null pointer.

Personally, I would probably only support the second use-case and use an explicit conversion to `bool` instead:

```
explicit operator bool() const { return this->mPtr; }
```

The overloads for `const` are obviously intended to propagate constness of the smart pointer to the pointed to objects.